# How to display the "actual size" on any screen?

Tags: monitor

I am doing a CAD program. I want to display drawings at actual size on screen, meaning that if I can place a ruler to measure lines on my screen and they should match. However screens have different dpis. How can I get the correct dpi and calculate the multiply factor for my program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the user to input the physical dimensions of the display. Details below...

- Given what X thinks the physical size and resolution of the console are, you can calculate the physical size X believes your monitor is:

  $  xdpyinfo | grep -E 'dimensions|resolution'
- The physical size of the monitor determined by the X system is the total dots divided by the dots per inch. Using your ruler, you can calculate the actual dots per inch and tell the X system what that is:

  $ xrandr --dpi 200
- If you have more than one monitor, you will also have to specify the name of the monitor via --output.
- Your cad program might display images. In which case, you need to know the size and resolution of the image. The imagemagick package contains idetify:

  $ identify -verbose FILE-NAME | grep -E 'Geometry|Resolution|Print size|Units'

Image viewers like feh and geeqie like to use a 1:1 image pixel to display pixel when displaying at image. A typical image editor will create an image at 300 dpi while am emailed image may report 72 dpi.

- Correct the image dpi. There is no need to change the image itself. (The actual value in the image is recorded in pixels-per-centimeter.)

  $ convert -units PixelsPerInch INPUT-IMAGE -density DESIRED-DPI OUTPUT-IMAGE

Answer (score 0):

To know the pixel density of a screen, you need two pieces of information, physical size and resolution.
While resolution can be determined programmatically, physical size cannot. (afaik)

There are some implementations of this idea where the software asks the user what their screen size is, and uses that to determine the pixel density.
Examples:
http://www.sizeis.com/
http://pective.com/pic/frog

Alternatively, some interfaces ask the user to calibrate using an item of fixed size- say by adjusting a slider till a digital silhouette matches a credit card.
Examples:
http://mwctoys.com/REVIEW_060412a.htm (see the second image)
http://beta.lifesizer.com/images/featured

In any case you will have to determine the physical size of the monitor to calculate the pixel density.